# Incomprehensible behavior with microtype \lsstyle

Tags: microtype

`Microtype`'s `\lsstyle` seems to cause problems related to math mode, which have been the subject of a few questions already (I must confess to not understanding it all).

I'm dealing with a behavior that seems math mode-related, but can't even understand the “pattern” of the problem.

In the following MWE, the command `\ecl{}` followed by a space should induce a space in the output.  For some reason, if it is called after a `\lsstyle`, it does *not* have that following space on its *first* appearance, but it *does* have it for the ones *after* that. I understand neither behavior. Any ideas as to what causes them, and how to fix it?

```
    
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage [%
                    letterspace=50% for \textls{} and {\lsstyle }
                ]
                {microtype}
    
    \newcommand\ecl[1]
                {%
                    \textnormal{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}%
                }
    
    \begin  {document}
            
            \lsstyle
            
            Some text
            \ecl{A} B %the space after "\ecl{A}" is somehow "cancelled"
            and more text
            \ecl{A} B %that same space appears as expected
            and more text
            
    \end    {document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't trace everything (using nested font changes and math within letterspaced section is unusual...)

But you can add a box to prevent the lookahead

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage [%
                    letterspace=50% for \textls{text} and {\lsstyle }
                ]
                {microtype}
    
    \newcommand\ecl[1]
                {%
                    \textnormal{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}\mbox{}%
                }
    
    \begin  {document}
            \lsstyle
            
            Some text
            \ecl{A} B %the space after "\ecl{A}" is somehow "cancelled"
            and more text
            \ecl{A} B %that same space appears as expected
            and more text
            
    \end    {document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @David Carlisle.

I just noticed defining \ecl{} as "{\rm $\langle$#1$\rangle$}" does the trick too. Not sure why!

Comment: @Rpy `\rm` has been deprecated for about 30 years.

Comment: @Rpy don't use `\rm` it's not defined by default.  `\text...` commands look ahead  for italic correction which is probably the issue here

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's the math mode that somehow has problems. However, you want `\textlangle` and `\textrangle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  letterspace=50,
]{microtype}

\newcommand\ecl[1]{%
  \textnormal{\textlangle #1\textrangle}%
}

\begin{document}

\lsstyle

Some text \ecl{A} B and more text \ecl{A} B and more text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know these existed in text mode—thanks a lot!